# Unable to specify colors with several geom_point and geom_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have three data frames (different sizes).
I created a graph with these three df. It's ok but I don't find the right way to specify colors of each graph. 
Here is what I did:

First case, I tried using `scale_color_manual` with definition inside the `aes`.

```
  ggplot()+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=map$MD, x=map$N,color="0"), method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 21),se=F)+
  geom_point(aes(y=whtc[seq(1,1800,by=2),"M"], x=whtc[seq(1,1800,by=2),"N"], color="1"))+
  geom_point(aes(y=etc[seq(1,1800,by=2),"M"], x=etc[seq(1,1800,by=2),"N"], color="2"))+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,4000),
                ylim = c(0,400))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), 
                     breaks = seq(0,5000, by=1000))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,500, by=100),
                     labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE,digits = 2))+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("0"="gray", "1"="blue","2"="red"),
                     labels = c("0"="Full load line", "1"="WHTC", "2"="ETC"),
                     name=NULL)
```

I get the error: `Error: geom_point requires the following missing aesthetics: x, y`
(? without the `color` variables it yields a graph)

Second case, I tried to specify the color outside the `aes`. But there, all the dots (geom_point) are the color of the last call, namely red.

```
  ggplot()+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=map$MD, x=map$N),color="gray", method = "lm",
              formula = y ~ poly(x, 21),se=F)+
  geom_point(aes(y=whtc[seq(1,1800,by=5),"M"], x=whtc[seq(1,1800,by=5),"N"]), color="blue")+
  geom_point(aes(y=etc[seq(1,1800,by=5),"M"], x=etc[seq(1,1800,by=5),"N"]), color="red")+
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(0,4000),
                  ylim = c(0,400))+
  scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0, 0), 
                     breaks = seq(0,5000, by=1000))+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,500, by=100),
                     labels = function(x) format(x, scientific = TRUE,digits = 2))
```

Here is a head of the df:

```
> dput(head(map))
structure(list(N = c(781.2, 783.3, 788.7, 795.6, 797.4, 807), 
    MD = c(202.6217, 210.3273, 216.0959, 215.3469, 205.2619, 
    212.3705)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(whtc))
structure(list(time = 1:6, speed = c(800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 
800), torque = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
> dput(head(etc))
structure(list(time = 1:6, N = c(800, 800, 800, 800, 800, 800
), M = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Do not use `$` and you're probably better off reshaping your data(quick glance). I also don't see you specifying the data arg.

Comment: What are these lines supposed to do? `whtc[seq(1,1800,by=5),"N"]` `whtc` does not appear to have N and M.

Comment: whtc[seq(1,1800,by=5),"N"] is to reduce the amount of points to reduce the size of the graph (happened in some previous projects). You are right... I'm confused... sorry... thanks